# spring-boot - External log4j configuration not working

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, log4j, properties-file

I am trying to do a setup for production environment, so I wanted to keep `log4j.properties` out of my application jar file.

For that I have kept my `application.properties` and `log4j.properties` files parallel to my spring-boot jar file. And I have given `logging.config: file:log4j.properties` in my application.properties. This doesn't seem to work. Spring is still picking up the log4j.properties file which is placed inside the jar file.

I have tried giving the absolute path in `logging.config` property like `C:\Users\furquan\project\jars\log4j.properties`, but it still the log4j.properties that was being used was the one inside the jar file.

Please help, its important !!!

Comment: you have to put in the specific directory : `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` if you did not.

Answer (score 0):

```
-Dlogging.config=/path/to/log4j.properties
```

Or you can specify it in your `application.properties` or `bootstrap.properties`.

From [26.5 Custom log configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

**And just a note:**

After spring boot 1.4, Log4j 1 support has been removed. So maybe you can consider use the default logback, or use log4j2 instead.

Comment: do I need to specify `file:` like `-Dlogging.config=file:/path/to/log4j.properties`

Comment: I tried this too, it doesn,t seem to work, this is what i tried : `java -jar webService.jar -Dlogging.config=file:C:\Users\furquan\project\deliverable\webservice\log4j.properties` and `java -jar webService.jar -Dlogging.config=C:\Users\furquan\project\deliverable\webservice\log4j.properties`.

Comment: in windows. you should use "\\" like "C:\\Users\\furquan\\....", or use "C:/Users/furquan/...."

Comment: Spring boot version? if still not work, you can debug `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener#initializeSystem` to see is the `logConfig` success initialized.

Comment: version is `1.2.0.RELEASE` and ok I will try debugging it